# shadow screen occur with Social Framework on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, social-framework

I create application with feature 'shared with facebook'
I use this code for make a facebook sharing

```
[facebookViewController setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"via %@", self.randomGame.name]];
NSLog(@"%@", self.resultImageView.image);
[facebookViewController addImage:self.resultImageView.image];
[facebookViewController setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Dialog Did Cancel");
    }
}];

[self presentViewController:facebookViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I already have allocation/initialization facebookViewController object with SLComposeViewController.

first time I share there is no problem.
But, I share second time I get a shadow screen like this

[image]

can anyone help ?
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but every time you present the facebook popover you also need to dismiss it in the completion block like

```
[facebookViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I done it with code

```
facebookViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[facebookViewController setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"via %@", self.randomGame.name]];
[facebookViewController addImage:self.resultImageView.image];

[self presentViewController:facebookViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```